# Create a document from an XML-file in Word 2007 or OpenOffice/LibreOffice

Tags: xml, ms-word, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, word-2007

Does someone know (and can guide me to) an (relativly) easy way to 'convert' a XML-file into a document in Word 2007 or OO/LO.

I am looking for something like drag-n-drop, similar to Excel. And the result shall be editable. Basically create a template which is linked to the XML-file and creates the final document on request.

I have read a lot about XML and document conversion using XSLT, but this is mostly related to the internal docx/odt-structure and much to complicated for my purpose.

*Short explantion of the problem background*:

I have my CV in form of an XML (where it's easier to maintain and better structured) and would like to generate from this XML-file a proper formatted Word97/OO/LO document. This implies that there must be a option to process repetitions (some solutions can't do this as far as I understood)

Comment: With XML/XSLT on the table, your question would still be too broad; without it, your question is not about programming and therefore off-topic.  Either way, your question as it stands is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: where would bei a better place to put it?

Comment: Word 2013 and later come with an XML mapping pane that allows you to add/update a so called "Custom XML" document to your Word document and then drag and drop nodes from the XML into your document. The XML content will be rendered within content controls.

Comment: @Dirk - I did know this, is there a similar way in 2007 for exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

There are programs out there that you can purchase such as Altova StyleVision, or online at Coolutils.com. If you want it to do exactly what you want it to do, and be free, using XSLT to convert is going to be your best option. A good demo is available from Microsoft here: [Using XSLT and Open XML to Create a Word 2007 Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx)